# Process.Kill() Method is Missing

Tags: c#

So I've looked around all over the place and nobody seems to have this problem. I added using System.Diagnostics to the list of references, so Process exists, but not the Kill method. Nowhere does it show up in the Intellisense menu. It has a Start method. No Kill method. It has a GetProcessesByName method but no Kill method. What is going on here?

```
foreach(var x in objServerList)
{
    Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("myproc.exe", x);
    proc.ki //nope it's missing, not in the long list of options
    Process.ki //nope, not there either
}
```

Comment: Isn't that an array? So proc is not going to have it but proc[0] would?

Comment: Yep that's the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proc` is an array of `Process` so it'll have methods relevant to arrays. Access a specific index and then you will have the methods of the `Process` type:

```
proc[index].Kill()
```

---

By the way your second attempt of `Process.Kill` does not work because the class `Process` does not have a static method of `Kill`

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle - you are welcome :) Please consider question as solved :)